# Measurement level of changes in test score

Tags: t-test

I have a question. In a study that I am acquainted with, the goal is to test for the effectiveness of a new psychotherapy method. The dependent variable is stress as assessed per PSQ (Perceived stress questionnaire).

If I want to look for differences between various groups (e.g. sex, education, experience with psychotherapy etc.) after the psychotherapy, does it make sense to study CHANGES between two time points (t2-t1) or do I have to inspect every data point on its own.

So can I for example calculate an independent t-test between males and females with CHANGES OF STRESS as a dependent variable, so not the stress score per se but the change of it between the two time points. Do you know what I mean, does my question make sense? And is the measurement level of stress score CHANGE also at least interval scale just as the Perceived stress score itself?

I hope my question makes sense. :)

Thanks a lot already in advance

Kind regards,
Helena

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking whether a paired t test
is the same thing as a one-sample t test on the
paired differences. If so, the answer is Yes.

**Simulated data.** I illustrate using fake paired data simulated in R as
follows.

```
set.seed(519)  # for reproducibility
before = round(rnorm(100, 200, 25))
increase = round(rnorm(100, 6, 6))
after = before + increase
diff = after - before
```

In the case of *actual experimental* data, you would see `before` and `after` as you look at test scores, and `increase`
would be available only on upon taking differences. [Please ignore the variable `increase` used only for simulation; it is the same as `diff`/]

Datapoints for the first six of 100 simulated
subjects are as follows:

```
head(cbind(before, after, diff))

      before after diff
[1,]    192   195     3
[2,]    230   236     6
[3,]    202   197    -5
[4,]    153   151    -2
[5,]    239   249    10
[6,]    178   179     1
```

We show a stripchart (dotplot) of `diff`. Over 3/4, but not all, of the subjects show positive differences.
[For our purposes, individual graphs of `before` and `after` are not useful; they would not show pairing and so might be misleading.]

```
stripchart(diff, meth="stack", pch=20, ylim=c(1,1.1), 
           main="Differences [After - Before]]")
abline(v=0, col="green2")
mean(diff > 0)
[1] 0.77
```

[image]

**Correlation.** On expects `before` and `after` scores to be correlated because of the pairing: the first 'before'
score is from the same subject as the first `after` score. Thus, there will typically be positive association between `before` and `after`, even if not typically as strong as in my simulated data.

The correlation $r$ between 'before' and 'after' is
nearly $1$ and a scatterplot shows a nearly linear
pattern for pairs. Points below the 45-degree line correspond to subjects that showed no improvement.

```
cor(before, after)
[1] 0.9696317

plot(before, after, pch=20)
abline(a=0, b=1, col="green3")
```

[image]

**Tests.** Now we compare results from two t tests in R:
(a) a paired test for `before` and `after` and
(b) a one-sample t test for `diff`. Notice that
results are the same: the t statistic `8.3978`, estimated
improvement `5.53`, and (very small) P-value `3.347e-13` are identical between the two tests.

```
t.test(after, before, pair=T)  # paired test

        Paired t-test

data:  after and before
t = 8.3978, df = 99, p-value = 3.347e-13
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.223386 6.836614
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   5.53 

t.test(diff)   # one-sample test of 'diff'

        One Sample t-test

data:  diff
t = 8.3978, df = 99, p-value = 3.347e-13
alternative hypothesis: 
  true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.223386 6.836614
sample estimates:
mean of x 
     5.53
```

**Incorrect two-sample t tests.** However, if you were ***incorrectly*** to do a *two-sample* t test,
then the `before` and `after` are treated as two independent samples ('pairing' is ignored), and
results of the test are substantially
different---both numerically and in format.

The 'Welch' t test, which does not assume equal variances, is shown in full; only the P-value of the 'pooled' t test is shown. Neither of these incorrect
tests shows a significant difference between 'before' and 'after'.

```
t.test(before, after)  # 'before' & 'after'
                       # treated as if independent

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  before and after
t = -1.4757, df = 197.79, p-value = 0.1416
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -12.919855   1.859855
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   201.31    206.84 

t.test(before, after, var.eq=T)$p.val  # pooled
[1] 0.1416086
```

*Note on nonparametric tests:* If data are not normal, you may choose
to use a Wicoxon signed-rank test to judge whether differences are mostly positive. Equivalently, you might do a paired test on `After` and `Before`.

```
wilcox.test(diff)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  diff
V = 4069, p-value = 3.052e-11
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0

wilcox.test(after, before, pair=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  after and before
V = 4069, p-value = 3.052e-11
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

However, it would be ***incorrect*** to do a two-sample Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon
rank sum test as if `Before` and `After` were two independent samples.

```
wilcox.test(after, before)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  after and before
W = 5602, p-value = 0.1416
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```